# Knockout JS Convert Array of Json object to validated observables

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

If I retrieve my view model from the server like this:

```
$.getJSON('/Items/', function (data) {
    var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    self.ViewModel(mapped);
});
```

and it has an array called Items that contain an Item, how can I turn all of the Item objects in the array to validatedObservables?  Is that even possible?

I use a table to select the Item I want to edit.  Here is my table:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: ViewModel().Items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: ItemName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: ItemCost"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: CategoryName"></td>
            <td><a data-bind="click: $root.EditItemPopup">Edit Item</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The click event is wired to this function:

```
self.ItemToEdit = ko.validatedObservable(Item);
self.EditItemPopup = function (something) {
    self.ItemToEdit(something);
    self.FindMatchingCategory(something.CategoryID());
    $("#editItemPopup").dialog("open");
};
```

When I call self.ItemToEdit().ItemName.isModified(false) it tells me the method is undefined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The knockout mapping plugin allows you to provide a *map* as a parameter when you perform your mapping.  You could create a map for your "Item" entity and in your map's `create` function you would apply the `validatedObservable` extender.  In your example you're sending an array to `ko.mapping.fromJS` so:

```
var itemMap = {
    create: function (options) {
        var koItem = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);//regular mapping
        var koItemValidated = ko.validatedObservable(koItem);//turn it into validatedObservable
        return koItemValidated;//return the validatedObservable
      }
};

$.getJSON('/Items/', function (data) {
    var itemsObj = {items:data};//create an object with a property of "items"
    var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {'items':itemMap});//for each item in items, use itemMap
    self.ViewModel(mapped);
});
```

[More info on the map param of ko.mapping here.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)